# pid_task() causes kernel panic, linux kernel 5.4

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I am trying to send a signal from the kernel space to the user space.
I have the below code and I am seeing a kernel panic.

```
[ 5230.132362] Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: prog_irq_handler+0x1d4/0x2cc [prog_mon]
[ 5230.146795] ---[ end Kernel panic - not syncing: stack-protector: Kernel stack is corrupted in: prog_irq_handler+0x1d4/0x2cc
```

Upon debugging some more, I found that the source of the panic is from the below function:

```
t = pid_task(find_pid_ns(id, &init_pid_ns), PIDTYPE_PID);
```

Referencing the value of "t" seems to cause an exception, resulting in a kernel panic.

Is there any known issue with the kernel 5.4 wrt the pid_task().
Any help will be appreciated.

My kernel comes from yocto, and it is:

branch ti-linux-5.4.y

commit 6f3bf13d53820fc12432d7052744be2ee046fc92 (HEAD -> ti-linux-5.4.y)
Merge: d2f658ed506d d5ef1ab82339
Author: LCPD Auto Merger lcpd_integration@list.ti.com
Date: Fri Apr 3 10:50:48 2020 -0500

https://git.ti.com/cgit/ti-linux-kernel/ti-linux-kernel/

Full code below:

```
send_signal(int val, int id, int sig)
{
struct kernel_siginfo info;
struct task_struct *t;
int ret;

ret = 0;

if ((id > 0) && (sig > 0)) {
memset(&info, 0, sizeof(struct siginfo));
info.si_signo = sig;

/* Using SI_KERNEL here results in real_time data not getting delivered to the user space signal handler */
info.si_code = SI_QUEUE;

/* Real time signals may have 32 bits of data */
info.si_int = val;
info._sifields._rt._sigval.sival_int = val;
info.si_errno = 0;

rcu_read_lock();
t = pid_task(find_pid_ns(id, &init_pid_ns), PIDTYPE_PID);
if(t == NULL) {
printk(KERN_ERR "%s: Invalid user handler PID %d\n", module_name, id);
rcu_read_unlock();
return -ENODEV;
}
ret = send_sig_info(sig, &info, t);
rcu_read_unlock();

if (ret < 0)
printk(KERN_INFO "%s: Failed to signal with data %d to user space\n", module_name, val);
}

return ret
}
```

Comment: You declare `info` variable of type `struct kernel_siginfo`, but fill it using size of **different** type `struct siginfo`, which is large. Probably, this causes stack corruption.

Comment: That indeed was the fix! memset with the proper size fixed the issue. Thanks a ton for helping me with this!